# Releasing a resource provided by a Future

Tags: java, future, race-condition

I'm creating an API that provides resources to the client which they will need to explicitly release (a la `Closeable.close()`) vi a `Future`. This pattern has a lot of nice features for our use case, but it comes with one wrinkle. If the client decides they no longer need the resource they can call `Future.cancel(true)` to cancel the (potentially expensive) allocation. However this introduces a race condition; if the resource finishes allocating before `.cancel()` is actually called then the future won’t actually free the resource.

Here’s an example:

```
Future<Resource> resource = service.requestResource();
try {
  doSomething(resource.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
  // by this point resource could be done, and .cancel() will be a no-op
  resource.cancel(true);
}
```

It seems the "right" thing to do is for clients to always attempt to release the resource after calling cancel, e.g.:

```
if (!resource.cancel(true)) {
  resource.get().close();
}
```

But this seems easy for a client to misuse. One option would be to use a [`ForwardingFuture`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ForwardingFuture.html) and decorate `.cancel()` with this close-if-done behavior, but that seems like it would violate the contract that `.cancel()` "[*will fail if the task has already completed*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-)".

Must `Future.cancel()` no-op if the task is done? Is there a better pattern that resolves this race condition in a less error-prone manner? Or is this just something `Future` isn't designed to handle, and we should avoid using it?

Comment: Who said failing is synonymous with no-op?

Comment: @shmosel fair point :) the spec is certainly vague about what will happen when `.cancel()` is called on an already-done object, however some [common](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#l164) [implementations](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a27bcd2f585ab90afc52173cbed38d1d573c51f3/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.java#L518) certainly treat it like a no-op, and I hesitate to deviate from that without some confidence I'm not violating a standard assumption.

Comment: For example, a caller could still call `Future.get()` get back the resource (since `.cancel()` failed) yet it would now be closed. Granted the caller explicitly called `.cancel()` but it still seems somewhat inconsistent. Another option would be to override `.get()` and `.isCancelled()` to claim the future *was* cancelled before completion, but now we're lying outright :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can expect your clients to at least call cancel just make it do the right thing by implementing it yourself:

```
public class CloseableFuture<V extends Closeable> extends FutureTask<V> {

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        if (!super.cancel(true)) {
            // Handle exception
            get().close();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the implementation I suggested in the question. The issue is whether this is acceptable given `Future`'s contract. In particular this implementation would mean that `.isCancelled()` could return `false` yet the object the future returns is unusable. Returning `false` is also somewhat of a misnomer.

Comment: "..But this seems easy for a client to misuse.. "  Yes, it does.